# how to call the function when the page first loaded in backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

How to call the updateh1Css when the page first load? For now, it works when the window is resized, but I also want to call it when the page first load.

```
var SubheaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'gallery',
    tagName: 'div',

    initialize: function() {
        $(window).on('resize', this.updateh1Css);
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(subheaderTemplate);
    },

    updateh1Css: function() {
        var pad_top = Math.floor($('#minor').height() * 0.4);
        var pad_left = Math.floor($('#minor').width() * 0.07);
        var pad = pad_top + 'px 0px 0px ' + pad_left + 'px';

        $('#cover h1').css({'padding': pad});
    }
});
```

Comment: Alright, using _.defer(function(){...}); will get elements height and width when the page first loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you can use `$(document).ready`

```
initialize: function() {
    $(window).on('resize', this.updateh1Css);
    $(document).ready(this.updateh1Css);
    this.render();
}
```

This will make it run when the document first finishes loaded.

Comment: How did you use it? `$(document).ready` always fires right after the page has loaded.

Comment: i used it in the way you write. I do not know why it doesn't work.

Comment: It's impossible to help any further without knowing more about the code. If you're rendering in your initialize then isn't the page already loaded? Why can't you just call the function immediately with `this.updateh1Css();`?

Comment: Actually, the function is executed, but the height and width can not be got, they are null.